# Ongoing Notification and singleTop-Flag

Tags: android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

Most of you who are familiar with the Notification and PendingIntent APIs will know that setLatestEventInfo is deprecated now.

I am therefore trying to replace my existing code (depending on the deprecated method):

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
    activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getString(R.string.notify),System.currentTimeMillis());
    PendingIntent startIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, getString(R.string.notify), getString(R.string.notifysummary), startIntent);
    this.startForeground(1234,notification);
```

As you may guess, I am calling this from inside a service that runs in the background. When the service starts, it will bring up the notification. This is a persistent, ongoing notification that brings the activity "Activity.class" to front in case it exists and creates a new instance of the activity in case it was killed meanwhile. Works fine without any problems.

Now, wanting to migrate to the newer API level, I am trying to replace the above code with the following [NotificationBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) example:

```
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);            
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent startIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent,  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentText("App running").setContentTitle("My app").setOngoing(true).setAutoCancel(false).setContentIntent(startIntent).build();
        this.startForeground(1234,notification);
```

But clicking on the Notification does not have any effect. However, I already tried "Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" because documentation says I should. This creates a new task even if the activity is already on top, in constrast to what the doc says: [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29), [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK).

Did anybody encounter the same problem? How to construct a persistent notification that is NOT dismissed when clicked and brings the activity to top if somewhere on the stack, else creates a new instance of it?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
PendingIntent startIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent,  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

You are passing an `Intent` flag to `getActivity()`. The 4th parameter for `getActivity()` takes `PendingIntent` flags, such as:

- PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
- PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE
- PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT
- PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

You are passing `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` as the 4th parameter. That constance actually has the value 0x20000000. Coincidentally, `PendingIntent.NO_CREATE` also has the value 0x20000000, so what you are doing is the same as this:

```
PendingIntent startIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, activityIntent,  PendingIntent.NO_CREATE);
```

That's your problem.

Just set the 4th parameter to `getActivity()` to `0`, like in your original code.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That was (beneath some other flaws) the cause. Fixed it now. Thanks a lot.